# I can't seem to retrieve data from mongodb using Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I'm having trouble retrieving data from a mongodb collection which I believe has been inserted correctly.

So here is my example code...

```
var db = require('./database');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/db', function (req, res) {
        db.collection('myCollection', function (err, myCollection) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }

            var docrow = {
                // no id specified, we'll let mongodb handle that
                name: 'Mark',
                date: '2013/09/11',
                description: 'Some text here'
            };

            console.log('I GET HERE OK');

            myCollection.insert(docrow, { safe: true }, function (err, insertedDocument) {
                console.log('BUT I DONT GET HERE?');

                if (err && err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) {
                    return console.log('This document already exists');
                } else if (err) {
                    return console.log('Something bad happened');
                }

                myCollection.find({ name: 'Mark' }, function (err, docs) {
                    docs.each(function (err, doc) {
                        console.log(doc);
                    });
                });
            });


            res.end('OK we made it');
        });
    });
};
```

...and the database.js file is...

```
var Db         = require('mongodb').Db,
    Connection = require('mongodb').Connection,
    Server     = require('mongodb').Server;

var host = process.env['MONGO_NODE_DRIVER_HOST'] != null ? process.env['MONGO_NODE_DRIVER_HOST'] : 'localhost';
var port = process.env['MONGO_NODE_DRIVER_PORT'] != null ? process.env['MONGO_NODE_DRIVER_PORT'] : Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;

/*
    w:1 tells mongo to wait until at least one confirmed write has succeeded before calling any callbacks
 */
var flags = { w: 1 };
var server = new Server(host, port, { auto_reconnect: true, poolSize: 20 });
var db = new Db('TestDBName', server, flags);

module.exports = db;
```

It looks like I'm able to create a Collection (`myCollection`) without error, and calling `insert` on the collection doesn't error either, but also doesn't appear to get any where near inside the callback function for it to trigger either an error or handle a success?

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Hi Integralist, did the answer helped or not?

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs unfortunately not :-( just tried it and I still couldn't even get inside the `myCollection.insert` callback

Comment: Oh my fault - you initialize database wrong way, I will update my answer in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to mongodb it is asynchronous method, so it will return client handler in callback, and this `client` handler have to be used onwards instead of handle of that Db object. So change this:

```
var db = new Db('TestDBName', server, flags);
```

To this:

```
new Db('TestDBName', server, flags).open(function(err, client) {
  if(err) throw err;

  // client - is the guy you are looking for instead of `db` you had
});
```

As well change:

```
myCollection.find({ name: 'Mark' }, function (err, docs) {
```

To:

```
myCollection.find({ name: 'Mark' }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
```

It is the only exception with mongo-native where you have to use `.toArray` instead of direct callback.